# Remove element from array (splice)

Tags: javascript, arrays, element, splice

Basic question on `.splice()` method, and how best to remove an element from an array.

I want to remove an item from an array with `.splice()` but when I do, I want to have the original array **minus** the removed element returned. `.splice()` returns the **removed element** instead.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
var newArr = arr.splice(3, 1)

console.log(newArr) // [4]

// whereas I want [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

What's the best, and most eloquent way to do this?

Comment: If you log `arr`, you'll find the elements have been removed from it. They've been returned and assigned to `newArr` by the splice function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.splice` *mutates the array in place* and returns the removed elements. So unless you actually *need* a function that returns the array itself, just access `arr`:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
arr.splice(3, 1)
console.log(arr) //  [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

---

You can create a wrapper function that performs the splice and returns the array:

```
function remove(arr, index) {
  arr.splice(index, 1)
  return arr;
}

var newArr = remove(arr, 3);
// Note: `newArr` is not a new array, it has the same value as `arr`
```

---

If you want to *create a new array*, without mutating the original array, you could use `.filter`:

```
var newArr = arr.filter(function(element, index) {
  return index !== 3;
}); // [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
arr; // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: `arr` is updated `array` right ? Why not just use it ?

Comment: @Rayon: Ask the OP ;) But yeah, maybe they didn't know about that, let me clarify that.

Comment: I thought that is the first thing to suggest.. If he is asking, he does/may not know how it is...

Comment: @Rayon: Well, they say they want that a function that *returns* the array. There could be use cases where something like this makes sense.

Comment: – Yeah! Very much possible... :)

Comment: Felix's solution is fine, just surprised there isn't a method that returns the reduced array in one. I've got a list of contacts, I wanted to click a 'remove contact' button that removes that object from the array. So, I want the original array altered accordingly. In the end I just removed it first, and then accessed the original array.

Comment: in place should be bolded ;)

Answer (score 6):

Using the spread operator, you can do:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    indexToRemove = 3,
    newArr = [
      ...arr.slice(0,indexToRemove),
      ...arr.slice(indexToRemove+1)
    ]
```

Or if you want to use ES5, it can look something like:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    indexToRemove = 3,
    newArr = [].concat(arr.slice(0,indexToRemove)).concat(arr.slice(indexToRemove+1))
```

Comment: Lets call it *spread element*, not spread *operator*. It's not an operator, even if MDN says so.

Comment: Have seen this method before. It's a bit verbose for this situation but I agree that could be useful in other, perhaps more complex scenarios.

Comment: What you are suggesting can be done by just using `.filter`, which amounts to less code and doesn't generate unnecessary intermediate arrays: `newArr = arr.filter((_, i) => i !== indexToRemove)`